# How to create label in SharePoint online and set the retention period?

Tags: sharepoint

How to add retention period in SharePoint online for the following cases
Retain active agreements indefinitely.

Retain inactive agreements for seven years once marked inactive

Thanks
Raja

Answer (score 0):

We can create retention policies and retention labels in  Microsoft 365 compliance center, please refer to the below articles for more about retention policies and retention labels:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/get-started-with-retention?view=o365-worldwide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-retention-policies?view=o365-worldwide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-apply-retention-labels?view=o365-worldwide